# creating a physic body with shape of texture is causing collision conflicts in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I got 2 sprites with physicsBody, one is a ball and other is an item that you can grab when they collide.

The problem is that if I create the physicsBody like this

```
self.ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: TextureManager.sharedInstance.getTexture(withName: self.ballItem.getId())!, size: CGSize(width: 96, height: 96))
```

Whenever both items collide, they collide like 100 times or so. If i create it like this:

```
self.ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.ball.size.width / 2)
```

That doesn't happen and the behavior is normal.

My issue with not using circleOfRadius is that all my balls aren't a circle shape, so how can I solve this? to have a perfect texture collision without calling `func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)` 100 times?

Btw, the item for example a coin, i create the physicsBody like this too:

```
self.coinItem.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.coinItem.size.width / 2)
```

Any idea on what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: What is going on is you do not have a circle for a physics body, you have a bunch of very tiny lines that look like a circle from far away.  This means your body will have multiple contact points happening.  If you know your `SKPhysicsBody` is a circle, then use the circle, otherwise you will experience what you see, a very very jagged polygon.

Comment: Oh my god :( so then how can solve this? i mean i really need a texture shape body, because when it falls, it looks really weird because it rotates like a circle, looks like it's floating... any ideas ? thanks for replying knight

Comment: what do you mean it is floating?  On your view, set `showPhysics = true` to see the physics body, then adjust the radius to fit inside of your texture

Comment: If the issue is that it rotates, then just set allowsRotation = false on your self.ball.physicsBody

Comment: I think that in order to explain myself better, i have to show you my game, is juggling king, basically you do jugs with different balls, now im adding 15 more.. and some of them aren't perfect circles... when they fall to the ground, they rotate, as normal, it looks fantastic.. now the problem is for objects that aren't circle shaped, for instance, im adding a chicken. So the chicken when on ground, and starts rotating very unrealistically with a shape of a circle which is incorrect, that's why i say it looks like it's floating in mid air, like it's not touching the ground.

Comment: Then you have to set up a different physicsBody for the chicken, like a rectangle instead. An alternative would for whenever the collision does happen then set the physicsBody = nil so that you wont have any more contact points, or you could even run an action that disables the physics body for x amount of time.

Comment: oh snap :( i don't know why they would add a physics with texture if it works so bad, i thought it would work as in Box2D where the physics on those objects is excellent. I used it in AndEngine and never had a problem with texture shaped physic bodies. Okay, looks like i have no other way then.. what about if the shape is like a diamond? (a square rotated 45 degrees) im screwed on that one.

Comment: Just have the image be of it un-rotated, create the square physicsBody, and then rotate it after you've created it.

Comment: Mmmm that's a good idea although i use the texture to show the "ball" in a carousel. It would look rotated there. I will see what i can do :/ i hate spritekit! haha

Comment: Well i found this tool to create simpler paths of sprites instead of letting spritekit make it for me, i will test it when i get home and if it works, i will reply my own post with it, but the page is http://insyncapp.net/SKPhysicsBodyPathGenerator.html

Comment: @DreamerNo56 setting the body to nil does not stop more checks,  something needs to be in place in the didBeginContact that says it was checked so skip

Comment: @msqar, SpriteKit physics is built on Box2D

Comment: @Knight0fDragon oh really? :( weird, in AndEngine this doesn't happen. Yes, i thought adding some collision flag, but what about if you add multiple coins on screen? it would work with only 1 item, but if you have maybe 3-4 on screen, it would only recognize 1 and not the others. :/ 
Can you check the site i posted to make the shape simpler? that prolly works, is like having a square or other type of simple shape.

Comment: @msqar you are always going to have multiple contact points, regardless of shape (even circle)  What I like to do is use is bit 32 on the categoryBitmask to flag it was checked,  then at the end of update, reset them

Comment: @Knight0fDragon yes, im using U32Int for the Physics Category. What I didn't understand was the reset on update cycle, what do you mean by resetting it? can you give me an example? i will try it out at home tonight.

Comment: `didFinishUpdate(){nodesThatCollided.forEach({$0.categoryBitmask &= ~(1<<31)})}`

Comment: I see, is that nodesThatCollided an array that i have to create and everytime something collides with another thing i just add it in there? So if my ball picks up a coin i should add both or only one of them?

Do you know why a circle shape collides only once for me, and other shapes such as a diamond shape should collide more times? I just don't know why that happens, i guess i will try a lot of things tonight and see what works for my specific case. Thanks guys.

Comment: It actually worked by using Paths! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching on Google, i found [this](http://insyncapp.net/SKPhysicsBodyPathGenerator.html) website which was really helpful.
Basically you upload the sprite and set the paths, and it will give you the code in Objective C, in Swift it's really similar.

For a diamond shape i had to do this

```
            let offsetX = self.ball.frame.size.width * self.ball.anchorPoint.x;
            let offsetY = self.ball.frame.size.height * self.ball.anchorPoint.y;
            let path = CGPathCreateMutable();

            CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 46 - offsetX, 94 - offsetY);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 94 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 44 - offsetX, 0 - offsetY);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 0 - offsetX, 46 - offsetY);

            CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

            return SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: path)
```

Thanks to knight0fDragon and dreamerNo56 for the help too :)